# Redirect with Discord OAuth strapi doesn't work

Tags: strapi, provider

When I click on the button, I go to the authorize page and it works.

Then I click on authorize and it redirects to the strapi page instead of redirecting me on my page.

It looks like this:

[image]

I put http://localhost:3000 on redirect but it doesn't redirect me to this page once I clicked on the popup authorize of discord.

This is my `server.ts` configuration for the test:

```
export default ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "localhost"),
  port: env.int("PORT", 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS"),
  },
  url: env("URL", "http://localhost:1337"),
});
```

Of course the redirect url is written in the discord app:
http://localhost:1337/api/connect/discord/callback

Answer (score 0):

You can pass "callback" with the url you want like this:
`https://api-codx.meetnav.com/api/connect/discord?callback=https://meet.yointly.com/login/discord`

Flow is like this:

- Client navigates to strapi
- Strapi redirects to discord (in this case)
- Discord returns to strapi
- Strapi returns to "callback" with a user token

Sorry can't find the documentation, last time it was hard to figure out so that's why I'm posting here.
Hope this helps